# How to create user with some permissions

Tags: command-line, networking, server, system-installation, permissions

When I add user **user1** and try to run command `ip route add`, an error appeared:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run commands which require superuser privileges, then add newly created user into `sudo` group:

```
usermod -aG sudo user1
```

Then, if you want to run a privileged command, you could use it like this:

```
sudo ip route add
```

If you want to run some commands without password prompt:

```
sudo visudo

user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get,/sbin/shutdown
```

Exit saving changes: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> -> <kbd>Y</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then `sudo apt-get install gedit` will not ask you about password.